# how to apply GraphViz attrs to networkx / pygraphviz

Tags: python, networkx, graphviz, pygraphviz

I'm using `networkx` (v2.5) for a dependency-analysis problem, and visualizing the data via `graphviz` / `pygraphviz` (v1.7) on ubuntu 20.04.  The contents of each node (`label` field) is a code block - so I'd like it LEFT justified.  The problem is I can't seem to change the default (CENTER justified).

**X/Y:** - my specific need is to make a `png` from a `networkx` graph where the node text is *left-justified* - I believe Graphviz/pygraphviz is the best ~trivial way to do so - but any FOSS way to accomplish this would be fine.

I successfully generate a `png` as desired, via the following simplified code, but the text is all *center-justified*.

```
from networkx import DiGraph, nx_agraph
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import write_dot

# graph is created via networkx:
graph = DiGraph()
graph.add_edge("node1", "node2")
graph.nodes["node1"]["label"] = get_code_sniped("node1")
# ...

# and converted / output to dot & png via (internally) pygraphviz
write_dot(graph, "/tmp/foo.dot") # appears correctly output
a_graph = nx_agraph.to_agraph(graph)
a_graph.layout(prog="dot")

# attempt to add attrs per defs in 
# https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:labeljust
a_graph.graph_attr.update(labeljust="l")  #  <----- has no effect on output
a_graph.graph_attr.update(nojustify=True) #  <-/

a_graph.draw("/tmp/foo.png") # <-- PNG outputs successfully, 
#                                  but all node text is CENTER justified
```

How can I modify the node text (specifically left-justifying it) in the PNG generated from my `networkx` graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears there is (undocumented, AFAICT) upstream/native `graphviz` behavior w.r.t. inheriting graph-level attributes.

setting `a_graph.graph_attr.update(...` is insufficient, as it is not inherited by child elements.  In order to for instance set `fontname`, the following works:

```
for node in formattable_graph.iternodes():
    node.attr["fontname"] = "Liberation Mono"
```

also, for text-justification, one can control this on a **Per line** basis by changing the line ending `"\l"` (Note: that is two bytes in python as it's not an actual escape char) and `"\r"` for left and right (respectively).

this will LEFT justify all lines

```
graph.nodes["node1"]["label"] = """my
  node label
  with newlines
""".replace("\n", "\l")
```